# Position of a new page with react router

Tags: reactjs

Using `react-router-dom` 5.2 - when I scroll down on page and then go to a new page it will be still scrolled down. How do I display it from top? Thanks

Comment: This is not an issue of  `react-router`. As you are not refreshing the page, the browser keeps the "scrolled down" value.

Comment: When you're on the new page you have to run following code from `useEffect` or `componentDidMount` based on your component type: `window.scrollTo(0,0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a component that scrolls to the top whenever the path changes.

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

Note: Make sure you place your component inside your `Router` in your App file.

```
<Router>
   <ScrollToTop />
   // other routes
</Router>
```